# Wrong EF migration script generated from same entity

Tags: .net-6.0, entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-6.0

While generating a migration, I just noticed some unwanted changes generated. I haven't made any such changes in my db entity.

```
migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<short>(
                name: "ReservationTypeId",
                table: "ReservationType",
                type: "smallint",
                nullable: false,
                oldClrType: typeof(short),
                oldType: "smallint")
                .Annotation("Relational:ColumnOrder", 0);
```

My db entity (no changes have been done here):

```
[Table("ReservationType")]
public class ReservationType
{
   [Key]
   [Column(Order = 0)]
   public short ReservationTypeId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My ef-configuration for this entity (no changes have been done here):

```
public class ReservationTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ReservationType>
{
   public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ReservationType> builder)
   {
     builder.Property(x => x.ReservationTypeId).ValueGeneratedNever();
   }
}
```

I am using:

- "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.13"
- "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.13"
- "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.13"
- .NET6

Can anyone help what is the cause and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downgraded the below packages to the previous version and everything works fine. The migration script is generating only the changes that I have made.

- "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.12"
- "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.12"

I am guessing something must have happened from Version="6.0.11"